# Как найти элементы с заданным условием C# LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Есть массив элементов типа int, например {-50, 2, 55, 985, 98515, -5354}

Помогите, пожалуйста, сообразить, как при помощи LINQ перебрать все эти элементы и добавить в новый массив только те, которые содержат две цифры 5. В массив должны поместиться след. элементы: { 55, 98515, -5354}.

foreach (var n in oldArray.Where(x => x.ToString().Contains('5'))) // этот кусок кода выводит только те элементы, в которых хотя бы раз содержалась пятерка. Помогите доработать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int numOf5(int number){
    number = Math.Abs(number);
    int ret = 0;
    while(number > 0){
        int rest = number%10;
        if (rest == 5) ret++;
        number = number / 10;       
    }
    return ret;
}
```

....

```
var array = new[] { -50, 2, 55, 985, 98515, -5354 };
foreach (var item in array.Where(x => numOf5(x) >= 2))
    Console.WriteLine(item);
```

....

```
55
98515
-5354
```

**UPD**

```
var array = new[] { -50, 2, 55, 985, 98515, -5354 };
foreach (var item in array.Where(x => x.ToString().Count(c=>c == '5') >= 2))
    Console.WriteLine(item);
```

Comment: Супер, спасибо! А можно ли сделать тоже самое но только со строковым типом?

Comment: обновил ответ, см UPD

Comment: Шикарно просто, спасибо, помогли! Моя ошибка была в том, что я в Count указывал сам массив и работал с кол-вом повторяющихся элементов